# Build an array of times using array_map - possibility of associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, array-map

I am trying to populate a dropdown list with quarter hour times. The key being the option value, and the value being the option text.

```
private function quarterHourTimes() {
      $formatter = function ($time) {
          return date('g:ia', $time);
      };
      $quarterHourSteps = range(25200, 68400, 900);

      return array_map($formatter, $quarterHourSteps);
}
```

The problem is that the above function works, but does not seem to work as an associative array. Is there an elegant solution for this problem?

For the key, I wish to have the time in the following format `date('H:i', $time);`

e.g. array should look like this:

```
$times = 
[
    ['07:00' => '7:00am'],
    ['07:15' => '7:15am'],
    ['07:30' => '7:30am'],
    ['07:45' => '7:45am'],
    ['08:00' => '8:00am'],
    ['08:15' => '8:15am'],
    ...
];
```

My Solution - Dump the array_map:

```
private function myQuarterHourTimes()
{


    $quarterHourSteps = range(25200, 68400, 900);

    $times = array();
    foreach(range($quarterHourSteps as $time)
    {
        $times[date('H:i', $time)] = date('g:ia', $time);
    }

    return $times;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the word "recursive": `array_map()` applies the function you give it to each element in the array you provide.  If the callback function you provide doesn't call itself, then there's no recursion.

Comment: @crennie - You are right, well spotted. - I tried to do it recursively before, and the question was related to doing it recursively. In attempt to solve the problem I removed the recursion, but forgot to change the title. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can be easily replaced with:

```
$result = array_reduce(range(25200, 68400, 900), function(&$cur, $x)
{
   $cur[date('H:i', $x)] = date('g:ia', $x);
   return $cur;
}, []);
```

with result in associative array like [this](http://3v4l.org/JrTfA).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like this

```
<?php
function formatter($time) {
          return array (date('g:i', $time) => date('g:ia', $time));
      };

 function quarterHourTimes() {

      $quarterHourSteps = range(25200, 68400, 900);

      return array_map('formatter', $quarterHourSteps);
}

print_r (quarterHourTimes());

?>
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/kaZdEQKK)

Comment: Your function is great - but the array keys are wrong. Need the following output. I guess that I cannot use array_map for this purpose. http://codepad.org/rGffpsho